# Error creating MultiPart Response in Jax-rs Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to return a Multipart response in a `@GET` call. No matter what I seem to do I always receive the same error:

> "Cannot get entity on a MultiPart instance (through reference chain: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart["entity"])"

I have `jersey-media-multipart` referenced in my `pom.xml`. I have tried adding references, removing references to no avail. I am using the (test) code below to create the `Response`:

```java
return Response.ok(new MultiPart()
                        .bodyPart("This is the first segment", new MediaType("text", "plain"))
                        .bodyPart("<outer><inner>value</inner></outer>", new MediaType("text", "xml"))).build();
```

I have the method annotated with:

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/json","multipart/mixed"})
```

as it can also return JSON under some conditions. Removing the `@Produces` completely or changing to only `"multipart/mixed"` does not alter the error message.

I also have an application class that registers the `MultiPartFeature.class`. I must add that I have a `@POST` method in this class in which I use `MultiPart` to retrieve `multipart/mixed` data without a problem. The relevant sections of the application class are as follows:

```java
public class OpApplication extends ResourceConfig
{
    public OpApplication()
    {
        // make the REST classes available
        super(Resource classes listed here...);

        // register the filters
        register(AuthorizationRequestFilter.class);
        register(AuthorizationResponseFilter.class);

        // register the multipart package for attachments
        packages("org.glassfish.jersey.examples.multipart");
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
}
```

The @GET method:

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/json","multipart/mixed"})
public Response getData(@Context UriInfo ui)
{
    boolean is_multipart = false;

    // retrieve the parameter map
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = ui.getQueryParameters();

    ParameterValidator parameterValidator = new ParameterValidator();

    // validate any existing parameters
    if (!parameterValidator.getCallParametersAreValid(queryParams))
    {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();

    }
    else   // check for the presence of parameter requesting a multipart response
    {
        is_multipart = parameterValidator.is_multipart();
    }


    JSONObject json = getDataAsJson(queryParams);

    if (json == null || json.length() == 0)
    {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
    else
    {
        // BodyParts would be gathered here. JSON and a file is most likely output
      /*  MultiPart objMultiPart = new MultiPart();
        BodyPart coverageBodyPart = new BodyPart().
                type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).
                entity(json);
        objMultiPart.getBodyParts().add(coverageBodyPart);
      */
        if (is_multipart)
            {
               // simple test
                return Response.ok(new MultiPart()
                        .bodyPart("This is the first segment", new MediaType("text", "plain"))
                        .bodyPart("<outer><inner>value</inner></outer>", new MediaType("text", "xml"))).build();
             }
            else
            {
                return Response.ok(json.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
            }
    }
}
```

The contents of the `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>opls</groupId>
    <artifactId>oprest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>6.7.5</version>
    <name>OPREST</name>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- PROJECT SPECIFIC DEPENDENCIES -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth1-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth1-signature</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20151123</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.wnameless</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-flattener</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>oplrs-${project.version}</finalName>
                <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <webXml>web/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                            <webResources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>web</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </webResources>

                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                    <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.ccf</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In response to the code example (thanks!) from Sergey I have created a new, simple endpoint. It still gives the same error:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartMediaTypes;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("/test")
public class Test
{
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MultiPartMediaTypes.MULTIPART_MIXED})
    public Response getData(@Context UriInfo ui) {
        final boolean condition = false;
        if (condition) {
            return Response.ok("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        }

        return Response.ok(
                new MultiPart()
                        .bodyPart("This is the first segment", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                        .bodyPart("<outer><inner>value</inner></outer>", MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE),
                MultiPartMediaTypes.MULTIPART_MIXED_TYPE
        ).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the full implementation (especially the `@GET` method)?

Comment: I have added a slightly cut down version of the code. Hopefully all relevant sections in place. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Do you receive the error (`Cannot get entity on a MultiPart instance (through reference chain: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart["entity"])`) on the client side or the service side? Could you please post the content of the`pom.xml` file as well?

Comment: The error is purely on the server side when producing the Response from the @GET method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Root cause analysis

The root cause is the absence of the explicit media type specification to the `Response.ok()` method call.

## Reduced solution example

The following example is an application (`JAR`) that uses Jetty as HTTP server and Java Servlet container.

### `pom.xml`

```xml
<project ...>
    ...

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### `Program` class

```java
import java.net.URI;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final URI uri = URI.create("http://0.0.0.0:8080/");
        final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class);
        resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        resourceConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);
        JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(uri, resourceConfig);
    }
}
```

### `TestResource` class

```java
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartMediaTypes;

@Path("/")
public class TestResource {
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MultiPartMediaTypes.MULTIPART_MIXED})
    public Response getData(@Context UriInfo ui) {
        final boolean condition = false;
        if (condition) {
            return Response.ok("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        }

        return Response.ok(
            new MultiPart()
                .bodyPart("This is the first segment", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .bodyPart("<outer><inner>value</inner></outer>", MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE),
            MultiPartMediaTypes.MULTIPART_MIXED_TYPE
        ).build();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help but unfortunately I am still getting the dreaded "Cannot get entity on a MultiPart instance (through reference chain: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart["entity"])" error in the response.

Comment: @MikeP, I have updated the answer with the almost all details. Could you please try to use the provided example: create a new project (`JAR` packaging instead of `WAR`), build it using the provided example, run it, and test it? Would be glad to know the result.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help Sergey. Turns out (after much digging) that there was a line of code in a ContainerResponseFilter that was setting the content-type header to application/json on all calls. That was causing the problem. However your code greatly assisted and I have marked as solution. Thanks again :)

Comment: @MikeP, my pleasure! Glad it has helped.